# Unwanted Data Dump to Screen in Localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, localhost

I'm guessing if you've seen something like this before, you know what it is.

Personally, I don't know where to start with describing this issue other than it looks like all of my standard output is somehow going to the console.

From what I can tell, this stuff is not called in my code, but then I generally work with Windows Forms, not ASP.NET.

I don't typically debug using localhost, but I wanted to make sure I had a lot of ASP.NET login security features removed before updating my personal website.

Here's what I see when I debug in localhost:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have Trace enabled on either the web.config or at the page level.

```
 <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
  </system.web>
```

Or:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Trace="true" Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
```

Comment: Thank you! I hopped it was something easy like that.